# How do I wait for a .each loop that makes async calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript code that updates some data to a database using a http handler, but this async call is made inside an `.each` loop. At the end of the loop I make a call to function `CancelChanges()` that refreshed the page. The problem is that the page seems to refresh before the database is updated. The `.each` loop seems to finish after the call to `CancelChanges()`. How can I make sure the page is refreshed after all the async calls are completed in the .each loop?

```
function SaveChanges() {
    if (PreSaveValidation()) {
        var allChangesSucceeded = true;
        var studioId = $("#param_studio_id").val();
        var baseDate = $("#param_selected_month").val().substring(6, 10) + $("#param_selected_month").val().substring(0,2);
        var currency = "CAD";
        var vacationPct = null;
        var gvAdmissible = null;

        $(".editable-unsaved").each( function() {
            var newSalary = $(this).text();
            var disciplineId = $(this).data("disciplineid");
            var seniorityId = $(this).data("seniorityid");
            var handlerCommand = "";
            if ($(this).data("valuetype") === "inflated") {
                handlerCommand = "AddAverageSalary";
            } else if ($(this).data("valuetype") === "actual") {
                handlerCommand = "UpdateAverageSalary";
            }
            $.get("WS/AverageSalary.ashx", { command: handlerCommand, studio_id: studioId, discipline_id: disciplineId, seniority_id: seniorityId, base_date: baseDate, currency: currency, salary: newSalary, vacation_pct: vacationPct, gv_admissible: gvAdmissible }).done(function (data) {
                if (data != "1") {
                    $(this).removeClass("editable-unsaved");
                    allChangesSucceeded = true;
                }
                else {
                    alert('fail');
                    allChangesSucceeded = false;
                }
            });
        });
        if(allChangesSucceeded) CancelChanges();
    }
}

function CancelChanges() {
    var href = window.location.href;
    href = href.split('#')[0];
    window.location.href = href;
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to start var allChangesSucceeded as false and not true? See, it loops through and fires off all the calls instantly and while waiting for the results to return, it finishes the loop and hits "if all changes succeeded" while it is still "true". The other thing is you should move that check  inside the "get" so that it checks after each call is returned. Otherwise, it will just check once.

Comment: You can use an array of $.Defered s and then $.when.apply($, array).

Comment: check  `promise` function  this https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change your structure a little bit, using a counter and calling CancelChanges when the counter equals the number of calls.

```
function SaveChanges() {
    if (PreSaveValidation()) {
        var studioId = $("#param_studio_id").val();
        var baseDate = $("#param_selected_month").val().substring(6, 10) + $("#param_selected_month").val().substring(0,2);
        var currency = "CAD";
        var vacationPct = null;
        var gvAdmissible = null;

        var editableUnsaveds = $(".editable-unsaved"); //cache the selector here, because selectors are costly
        var numOfGetsReturned = 0;            

        editableUnsaveds.each( function() {
            var newSalary = $(this).text();
            var disciplineId = $(this).data("disciplineid");
            var seniorityId = $(this).data("seniorityid");
            var handlerCommand = "";
            if ($(this).data("valuetype") === "inflated") {
                handlerCommand = "AddAverageSalary";
            } else if ($(this).data("valuetype") === "actual") {
                handlerCommand = "UpdateAverageSalary";
            }
            $.get("WS/AverageSalary.ashx", { command: handlerCommand, studio_id: studioId, discipline_id: disciplineId, seniority_id: seniorityId, base_date: baseDate, currency: currency, salary: newSalary, vacation_pct: vacationPct, gv_admissible: gvAdmissible }).done(function (data) {
                if (data != "1") {
                    $(this).removeClass("editable-unsaved");
                }
                else {
                    alert('fail');
                }
                if(editableUnsaveds.length === ++numOfGetsReturned){
                   CancelChanges(); //now it should call when the final get call finishes.
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

function CancelChanges() {
    var href = window.location.href;
    href = href.split('#')[0];
    window.location.href = href;
}
```

Comment: When I cache the selector, the .each loop seems to be skipped. It does not go inside the loop. I double checked the spelling.

Comment: Huh, does it work if you switch `$(".editable-unsaved")` out with editableUnsaveds everywhere where it is used?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it does iterate inside the loop, however, are you sure it's ++numberOfGetsReturned and not numberOfGetsReturned++. This condition doesn't seem to be true and it does not call CancelChanges(). I'll give it a try. I'm leaning towards your answer because it is more readable.

Comment: Yeah, if I could test it I'm guessing I could figure out what stupid mistake I made. Try `console.log(editableUnsaveds.length, numOfGetsReturned)` on the final line of the get statement.

Comment: I added your console.log statement right before the last if statement and the value of numOfGetsReturned is already at 2. How can that be? Very strange.

Comment: Oh, I think I know what it is, numOfGetsReturned should start at 0.

Comment: Wow this is very strange. When the line var numOfGetsReturned = 1; is executed, I hover the cursor over the variable and it tells me the value is 2! Something is incrementing it to 2 when it is being set to 1. What the? This seems to be a separate issue so I set it to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You could try using [Promises](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise) and [jQuery `$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Store a list of the ajax call promises:

```
var defereds = [];

$(".editable-unsaved").each( function() {
    //...
    defereds.push($.get("WS/AverageSalary.ashx" /*...*/));
}
$.when.apply($, defereds).done(function() {
    CancelChanges();
});
```

This should, hopefully, wait for all the ajax calls to finish before calling `CancelChanges()`

Comment: my thoughts exactly. Promises clean things up so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/). The [q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) is my favorite way to implement them. But since you're using JQuery, I'd recommend following a similar approach to what I outline below, but using `$.when`, instead of `q.allSettled`

I often use promises when scraping tons of websites at once -- I need to iterate through a long list of websites, make requests for content, and do something with the content when the requests return. The last thing I want to do is send requests one at a time, handling each one as it returns.

In the abstract, that looks something like this:

```
function scrapeFromMany() {
  var promises = [];

    _.forEach(urls, function(url) {

      // this makes the request
      var promise = scraper(url);

      // this stores the promise with the others you iterate through
      promises.push(promise); 
    });

  q.allSettled(promises).then(function(res) {
    // this function is executed when all of the promises (requests) have been resolved 

   console.log("Everything is done -- do something with the results.", res);
  });
}
```

Fwiw, promises aren't that easy to grok if you've never used them. If that's the case, plan on spending some time getting up to speed with the concepts. They'll change (for the much much better) the way you write async javascript, and they really are the blessed path with these sorts of operations.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronously call your check function within the "done" function handler. Keep track of how many requests have completed, and only do your processing once that's equal to the total number of expected requests.

```
if (PreSaveValidation()) {
    var allChangesSucceeded = true;
    var length = $(".editable-unsaved").length;
    var completedCount = 0;
    // ...

    $(".editable-unsaved").each( function() {
        // ...
        $.get("WS/AverageSalary.ashx", data).done(function (data) {

            completedCount++;

            if (data != "1") {
                $(this).removeClass("editable-unsaved");
                // don't set all changes succeeded to true here
            }
            else {
                alert('fail');
                allChangesSucceeded = false;
            }

            isComplete(length, completedCount, allChangesSucceeded);
        });
    });
}

function isComplete(totalLength, currentLength, allChangesSucceeded) {
    if (currentLength == totalLength) {

        // should this be !allChangesSucceeded?
        if (allChangesSucceeded) CancelChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are not waiting for the requests to complete to proceed with the loop.
To achieve so you have to set the "async" flag to false.
The call to the server should be like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "WS/AverageSalary.ashx",
        async: false,
        data:{ command: handlerCommand, studio_id: studioId, discipline_id: disciplineId, seniority_id: seniorityId, base_date: baseDate, currency: currency, salary: newSalary, vacation_pct: vacationPct, gv_admissible: gvAdmissible },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != "1") {
                $(this).removeClass("editable-unsaved");
                allChangesSucceeded = true;
            }
            else {
                alert('fail');
                allChangesSucceeded = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Setting the async flag to false will completely freeze the entire webpage while the request is pending. I don't think it's advisable in normal cases.